# Kafka multiple tenancy consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, multi-tenant

Hello we are starting to work with kafka with donetnet, we need to set up a multi tenancy environment. We've been looking at the references in the main github (confluent-kafka-dotnet). We noticed that the continuous consumer implementation is done using a backgroundservice, we would like to understand how we can use a model where we have one consumer per tenant.
Our questions are:

- If we adopt the model mentioned above, creating a backgroundservice per consumer, what problems are we subject to?
- If we have a structure of a backgroundservice and multiple tasks for each consumer, what problems are we subject to?

If you can help us, or have any suggestion/example of how we can do it, we would be very grateful for your support.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the problem. Are you familiar with how consumer groups in kafka work, in general? Are you only asking your question about one topic and multiple consumers? What is a "tenant" in your case?

Comment: It would be a one-topic outline for each consumer (each tenant is a consumer). 
We would not like to use a group at this time, it would be a 1 consumer x 1 topic relationship

Comment: Doesn't sound like you understand consumer groups. In order to track offsets or progress in the topic, all consumers need to be part of a group, even if there's only one of them

Comment: Yes, my mistake. We need a group even with a single consumer. But I still don't understand how I can create several of these groups to consume messages independently. In the following example, a background service is created with the consumer: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Web/RequestTimeConsumer.c. I would like to know how to do this with many consumers, I imagine that creating many backgroundservices is not ideal.

Comment: If you want independent offset tracking, you need multiple consumer instances and create them with different group ids. Maybe duplicating these JSON sections. Or refactoring the group id into some factory function to create the worker https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Web/appsettings.json#L19